# Is it possible to check, if a git tag is reachable from another git tag in same repo using remote commands?

Tags: git, git-remote, git-tag, git-rev-list, ls-remote

Is it possible to check if, a git tag/commit is reachable from another git tag/commit in a repo through remote git commands i.e without cloning the code.

I can do it locally using git rev-list or git merge-base.
I tried using git ls-remote, but unable to do so.

Comment: No. you have to have the repository locally to find what you want in the history.

Comment: @ckruczek, could you write an answer for this?

Comment: @Chococroc Thank you for the reminder. I added a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to interact with a git repository you have to clone it.

Use
`git clone <remote>` to get the repository locally and after that you can use your commands you already used before to filter.